# how to use named arguments in dask task graph

Tags: python, dask

How can I create a call with named arguments in creating a dask task graph? For instance:

```
def foo (x=1, y=2):
   ...

graph = { 'z': foo, "y=100" }
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Dask.delayed

You could use [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-overview.html) to generate a custom graph.

```
def foo(x=1, y=2):
    ...

x = delayed(foo)(x=1, y=2)
```

This is usually the best way to go.  It's fool-proof, simple, and what the dask developers are doing internally with new code.

#### Use positional arguments

If you *really* want to make a graph by hand you can use positional arguments

```
graph = {'z': (foo, 1, 100)}
```

#### Use apply

You can also use apply

```
from dask.compatibility import apply

graph = {'z': (apply, foo, [], {'y': 100})}
```